# backgroung image of the body disappears after changing tab on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

i have a site with a backgroung image with 1,32mb, that's located in css of the body, the problem is when i change tab in firefox and back again on my site the background disappears, and displays a white background... someone knows what's happing ?

//html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Cacilda Tour</title>
<link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

<!-- começo do codigo random imagens
var mypics=['toppo1.png','toppo2.png','toppo3.png'];
onload=function(){
    var oTd = document.getElementById('cel');
    var pic= 'topo/'+mypics[Math.floor(Math.random()*mypics.length)];
    oTd.style.backgroundImage='url('+pic+')';
}
//  fim do codigo de imagens -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="principal">
    <div class="cabecalho">

    <img id="cel" src="images/topo_transp.gif" border="0" >

    </div>
    <div class="menu">

    </div>
    <div class="conteudo">
        <div class="centroesq">
            <div class="titcentroesq">
            <p>Pacotes</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="centrodir">
            <div class="titcentrodir">
            <p>Corporativo</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rodape">

    </div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

//css

```
body{
background-image: url(../imagens/fundo.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:1065px;
}
.principal{
width:980px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.cabecalho{
float:left;
width:100%;
}
.cabecalho img {
width:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:980px; 
height:200px;
}
.menu{
float:left;
width:100%;
height:40px;
background-image: url(../imagens/fundomenu.png);
margin-top:8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
}
.conteudo{
float:left;
width:100%;
height:700px;
background-image: url(../imagens/fundomenu.png);
margin-top:8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
}
.centroesq{
float:left;
width:488px;
height:300px;
border-right:1px dotted #c0c0c0;
margin-top:8px;
}
.titcentroesq{
float:left;
width:460px;
height:32px;

margin-left:10px;
background-image: url(../imagens/fundotitulo.png);
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
line-height:2px;
color:#10468c;
font-family:arial;
font-size:105%;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:left;
padding-left:10px;
border:1px solid #fbca18;
}
.centrodir{
float:left;
width:490px;
height:300px;
margin-top:8px;
}
.titcentrodir{
float:left;
width:460px;
height:32px;

margin-left:10px;
background-image: url(../imagens/fundotitulo2.png);
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
line-height:2px;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:arial;
font-size:105%;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:left;
padding-left:10px;
border:1px solid #2b4688;
}
.rodape{
float:left;
width:100%;
height:95px;
background-image: url(../imagens/fundomenu.png);
margin-top:8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;

}
```

Comment: why you want to float left something when you are using `width: 100%`?

Comment: if you can provide the url you're working on, that will be great

Comment: http://www.datacode.com.br/clientes/cacildatour/

Comment: stay 1 min off the tab, you can see that it disappears...

Comment: The same for other comment, the size of the image is too large 1.3 Mb just for background, I don't think it is a good idea. If you are using Photoshop, try to save the image by the option: Save for Web and Device to reduce its size.I don't see any problem here on my Firefox except the image loaded too slow.

Comment: Toung, i did it in photoshop, and still not working... :(

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the problem is the image is too large. Try compressing it for the web.